# CakePHP 3: Form and Digest Auth in one App

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-3.x

I'm currently developing an application in CakePHP 3, this application contains a Web Front End and a plugin for API/WebServices that serves mobile apps.

The web front end login system rely on FORM Based Authentication and work perfectly, but i want to uses a Digest Based Auth to check user credentials on API Request.

The API request is a plugin on the same system made for me, and router via /api/users (example) endpoints to server mobile apps.

I trying to get the 2 ways of authentication with no luck and also try the JWT plugin with no luck.

Anybody has a solution to this or have a similar problem?

Thank you folks!

Comment: Can you attach some code examples to your question, otherwise don't expect too much help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after further investigation, the problem is all about CORS

[CORS Enabling](http://enable-cors.org/)

In Cake create a new beforeFilter with the following code:

```
$this->Security->csrfCheck = false;
```

And that's all.

Thanks folks!